Can't get my image in public folder React
I'm creating a React app and encountered error during building my project.
My project's structure is like this:
App:
--public
----apple.png
--src
----components
-------About
---------About.jsx
---------style.scss
In my style.scss (which is being imported in About.jsx) I have:
&__container::after{
    position: absolute;
    content: '';
    display: block;
    bottom: -101px;
    left: 50%;
    height: 750px;
    width: 760px;
    background-image: url('./../../../public/apple.png');
  }

I still have this error: GET http://127.0.0.1:5500/static/media/apple.70b0f1c0a74772ea2af6.png 404 (Not Found)
And you can see that I have the image in my build folder
enter image description here
I've also tried tens of different paths, moving my image from public (with creating 'images' folder and without) to src and so on, but nothing helped.
I've also tried removing the '.' in the beginning of the path:
 background-image: url('/public/images/apple.png');

But in this and other cases I can't even build my project

In your style.scss try background-image: url('/apple.png'); or background-image: url('../../public/apple.png');

It doesn't help :(
I can't build my project:
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../../apple.png' in 'C:(my path)......\src\components\About'

Have you tried both options?

Yes! The second one gives:
Creating an optimized production build...
Failed to compile.
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../../public/apple.png' in 'C:\Users.....\src\components\About'

Can you try to reproduce the issue in an online environment like codesandbox?
